# Multiple string append together with index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple string required original string to append different strings. Both of origin string and append string contains 1 int variable Based on my knowledge, both of following code are working but what is the best way to do it or if there is a better way to do it?
or is there any way I can write something like

```
newstrg = '{}{}'.format(org%OrgInt, appd%appdInt)
```

first method

```
org = "org__%s"
appd = "appd__%s"
orgInt = 1
appdInt = 7
newstrg = org % orgInt + appd % appdInt
print(newstrg)
org__1appd__7
```

Second method

```
org = "org__{}"
appd = "appd__{}"
orgInt = 1
appdInt = 7
newstrg = (org + appd).format(orgInt, appdInt)
org__1appd__7
```

Comment: better in what sense exactly?

Comment: better way to maintain or look for professional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
org_appd = {'org': 1, 'appd': 7}       
org = "org__{org}"
appd = "appd__{appd}"

newstrg = (org + appd).format(**org_appd)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about "org__{org}appd{appd}".format (org =1, appd= 7) or similar?  Your format string can be arbitrary, and it's cleaner to use named placeholders.

## edit

if the tokens and the numbers are variable, feed them in as a list of token-value pairs:

```
tokenpairs = [('org',1), ('appd', 7)] # etc
unit = lambda t,v : "{0}__{1}".format(t ,v)
renamed = "".join([unit (t, v) for t, v in tokenpairs])
```

Comment: for my org and appd string are actually variable as well